# SSL socket programming using glib

Tags: sockets, ssl, glib

I want to use an SSL socket from the within the glib framework (newbie). Is there a g_socket_xx() interface that I can use when doing SSL communications over a socket?
If not what are the alternatives?

Comment: Would appreciate some pointers on this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is [TLS (SSL) support](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/tls.html) in GIO.  If you use [GSocketClient](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GSocketClient.html) you can just set the tls property to true.